# prevent @ to be entered into input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent `@` to be entered into `input`. But it doesn't work, any idea why?

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', '[placeholder="x"]', function() {
    if (event.keyCode === 64) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r82wtea3/2/

Comment: You should use `event.which`. The other ways of getting the pressed key is not reliable across browsers.

Comment: @Eunice Chia check my answer

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log(event, event.which, String.fromCharCode(event.which));` as the first line of the anonymous function of `on()` in order to see whether the `if` should actually capture what you think it should be capturing?

Comment: Anyway, keyup event is too late to avoid default behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to pass parameter `event` to the function:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '[placeholder="x"]', function(event) { /*...*/ });
```

I suggest you to use `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode` for better compatibility. Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r82wtea3/5/). I have used `keypress` event instead of `keyup`.

Comment: so what is my issue actually?

Comment: @EuniceChia note that he switch from `keyup` to `keypress`. This approach is not working with `keyup`.

Comment: Listening to `keypress` isn't enough. What if the user inputs with an on-screen keyboard or pastes from the clipboard with their mouse?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', '[placeholder="x"]', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 50) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="x">
```

change your function to following:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', '[placeholder="x"]', function(event) {    
    if (event.keyCode === 50) {    
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `return false;` on `keypress` event when `event.which` is a certain value

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keypress', '[placeholder="x"]', function(event) {  
        if(event.which === 64){
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

which will more or less *kill off* the event..

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eaj93ocu/)..

Answer (score 0):

On `keyup` the `@` is not a single key. It is more like `ALT+Q`, or `CMD+L` on Mac. So the best way would be to check the `input` for existance of `@` in the value and to it manually. Otherwise use `keypress` with `64` as `keyCode`.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', '[placeholder="x"]', function() {
        var input = $(this);

        if ( input.val().indexOf("@") >= 0 ) {
            input.val(input.val().replace("@", ""));
        }
    });
});
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/r82wtea3/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't listen for a for a keypress-type event since it won't fire if the user pastes an `@` with their mouse. You also can't listen for one specific `keyCode` because there are multiple ways to input an `@` across different platforms and keyboard layouts.

You should be listening for a change-type event such as [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), and replace any occurrence of `@` with an empty string. Here's an example:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/@/g, '');
});
```

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/rLQWWb?editors=0010#0) with the example in action.